# Chemmacros - Multiple Values as coupling constant

Tags: chemistry, chemmacros

I'm using the `chemmacros` package for my thesis in chemistry. Now I want to write down NMR data. My peak is a double-double-duplett I have therefore 3 coupling constants. I use `\NMR`and `\J` in the `\experimental` enviroment but for multiple values for J it is not working.
It should look like this: J = 1.2, 2.3, 3.4 Hz 
I tried to put brackets around the values but it is not helping.

Here is the minimal example

```
\documentclass[english, 12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{
    modules=all  
}
\chemsetup[spectroscopy]{
    delta=ppm,
    use-equal
}
\sisetup{
    separate-uncertainty,
    per-mode=symbol,
    detect-all,
    range-phrase=--
}
\begin{document}
\section{chapter 1}
\blindtext
\begin{experimental}
    \NMR(500)[CDCl3]
    \val{6.05--6.01}(ddd, \J 9.9, 4.2, 1.4)
\end{experimental}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

A careful look into the package describe brought up the solution.

multiple coupling constants have to be seperated by `;`

so the line looks like this
`val{6.05--6.01}(ddd,\J{9.9;4.2;1.4})`